# How can you exclude a search term in an SQLite fulltext search?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I am using DB Browser for SQLite. The documentation for SQLite's fts3 [says](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html) "FTS is primarily designed to support Boolean full-text queries". I built a virtual table using fts4 and successfully executed a few WHERE ... MATCH queries. But the following attempts give errors:

```
SELECT id FROM histsearch WHERE id MATCH ("-1456" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT id FROM histsearch WHERE NOT EXIST id MATCH ("1457");
```

Is the problem in DB Browser or in SQLite? How else can I write this query so it will work?

Comment: The FTS query syntax is explained in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3).

Comment: I did not realize I was asking a question about FTS query syntax (I'd skimmed that section looking for "exclude" and searched on "Boolean", not the "set operations" section). I thought I was asking about SQLite or DB Browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's full text service (fts3) basically offers Boolean Mode by default, no search modifier needed. DB Browser uses fts's [standard query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_2), so NOT is not supported. To exclude a term, do something like

```
SELECT * FROM indexed WHERE indexed MATCH 'sqlite -database';
```

Edit: however, you cannot *only* exclude search terms in fulltext search:

> An FTS query may not consist entirely of terms or term-prefix queries with unary "-" operators attached to them.

You'll have to use NOT LIKE for that.